# How to make the value of the array of keys and values in php?

Tags: php, arrays

How to make the value of the array of keys and values in php ?
Do it all in one line is not going through an array, and use it for the built-in functions for working with arrays

```
$array = [
  '0' => 'Amsterdam',
  '1' => 'Berlin',
  '2' => 'Busingen',
];
```

Result:

```
$result= [
  'Amsterdam' => 'Amsterdam',
  'Berlin' => 'Berlin',
  'Busingen' => 'Busingen',
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
array_combine(array_values($array), array_values($array));
```

Or simply:

```
array_combine($array, $array);
```

Comment: good idea with `array_combine` but I's say it should be just `array_combine($array,$array)` (OP wants result array to consist of $array's values)

Comment: @MarkS @ Ben Fortune Thanks for the note. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function transformArrayKeyValue($array) {    

    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result[$value] = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Try this code. It should be do what you expected.

**Edit** : Fixed $key => $value....

Comment: Inefficient and doesn't work properly, check `$result[$key] = $key;` to `$result[$value] = $value;`